# Xcode is using wrong PATH when executing a run script

Tags: ios, xcode, path, run-script

When I try to execute a run script phase in Xcode 7.1 on Yosemite, I seem to be using the wrong PATH...

When I echo $PATH from the script, I get the following:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I have zero idea about how to fix this, and I've tried like a hundred different solutions, like adding a custom build variable, opening Xcode from terminal, etc.  Any suggestions?